# edit flash embed attribute

Tags: flash

I have a drop down menu that constantly appears behind an embedded flash video in IE,chrome if i set param tag attribute wmode="transparent" then it is working fine. But in my page flash video will come dynamic. I have to edit after it loads.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed video from YouTube you may add `&wmode=opaque` at the end of the URL. Other sites should have similar options...

BTW, wmode `opaque` is better/safer. wmode `transparent` is still quite buggy (not sure if full screen mode works in `transparent` wmode).

Comment: But how to add it to existing object

Comment: Can you post as many details as possible? Sample code would be nice, too. Otherwise is just guessing.

Comment: OK here is my code, <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="425" height="350" codebase="download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/…; <param name="src" value="youtube.com/v/Wj0UDs8kZWY"; /> <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="425" height="350" src="youtube.com/v/Wj0UDs8kZWY"></embed>; </object> I would like to add attribute wmode="transparent" to embed tag dynamically through jquery or javascript How?